# Throwing an exception which causes a destructor to be called crashes the program

Tags: c++, exception

Consider this small snippet of code, which is actually part of a larger codebase:

```
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
    }

    ~A()
    {
        std::cout << "~A" << std::endl;
    }
};

void f()
{
    A a;
    throw;
}

void g()
{
    try
    {
        f();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "Caught" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

For my particular case, the output turns out to be

```
A
~A

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

It seems that rather than the exception being caught, the program is just terminated. However, if I remove A's constructor, the exception *does* get caught.

Without closely analyzing the code, is it possible to know what causes this sort of behaviour?

Comment: Have you tried throwing anything specific, like an int (better: some regular  exception)? A single `throw` is normally intended to re-throw an already caught exception...

Comment: throw; `This form is only allowed when an exception is presently being handled (it calls std::terminate if used otherwise)`

Comment: I recommend you take some time to read e.g. [this `throw` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw). Because you're using it wrongly. Also http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: The `throw;` statement was used more of an example. It didn't matter what I was throwing, the result was the same - a crash.

Comment: Maybe you should edit your code then.

Answer (score 14):

A *throw-expression* with no operand, as in your code:

- Rethrows the currently handled exception (the same object, not a copy of it)
- Or, if there is no currently handled exception, calls `std::terminate`.

I am assuming `f()` is *not* being called while an exception is being handled (I imagine you're calling it directly from `main` or something). Thus, `std::terminate` is called.

The object `a` is irrelevant.

Comment: Please see my comment above. The `throw;` was only used as an example.